# Grails 3.3.5 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 not working?

Tags: grails, grails-3.3

I find `grails -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 war` is not working for my project, but `gradle -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 assemble` is working. Maybe `grails` not pass system properties to gradle ? And what should I do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by myself. Just add `org.gradle.jvmargs='-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8'` to `gradle.properties`